# Proving the convergence of the improper integral $\int_0^1 \operatorname{ln}(\operatorname{sin}x)dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove that

\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1 \operatorname{ln}(\operatorname{sin}x)dx
\end{equation*}

converges.

I tried to show this by decomposing

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{ln}(\operatorname{sin}x)=\operatorname{ln}(\frac{\operatorname{sin}x}{x}x)=\operatorname{ln}(\frac{\operatorname{sin}x}{x})+\operatorname{ln}x. 
\end{equation*}

However, I can't tell whether

\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1 \operatorname{ln}(\frac{\operatorname{sin}x}{x})dx 
\end{equation*}

converges.

I would appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but numerically speaking, the integral converges. You might be well suited to prove the convergence by contradiction and or by integrating a function that bounds the current one...

Comment: As an aside, $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\ln\sin x~dx ~=~ \int_0^\tfrac\pi2\ln\cos x~dx ~=~ -\frac\pi2~\ln2$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You only have a singularity at $x=0$. Try to compare the integrated function with another one that is asymptotically equivalent and that has an explicit primitive.

P.S. Alternatively, keep following your route and observe that $\log\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has no singularities on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: I can't think of a function to compare with.  Also how can I show that $\operatorname{log}(sinx/x)$ is improper integrable on [0,1]?

Comment: @takecare: Ok, forget about the comparison for a moment. Write $f(x)=\log\frac{\sin x}{x}$. This is a bounded function on $[0, 1]$. Therefore $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx$ is finite. That's all.

Comment: If you want to compare, try approximating $\sin x$ with $x$. You'll end up doing the same computations as user17762, basically.

Answer (score 0):

For $x \in [0,1]$, we have
$$\dfrac{x}2 \leq \sin(x) \leq x$$
Hence, we have
$$\log\left(\dfrac{x}2\right) \leq \log\left(\sin(x)\right) \leq \log\left(x \right)$$
This gives us that
$$\int_0^1\log\left(\dfrac{x}2\right)dx \leq \int_0^1\log\left(\sin(x)\right)dx \leq \int_0^1\log\left(x \right)dx$$
Hence, we have
$$-1-\log2 \leq \int_0^1\log\left(\sin(x)\right)dx \leq -1$$

**EDIT**: In case this was not clear, the integrability of $\log\left(\sin(x)\right)$ on $(0,1]$ is trivial, since the function is continuous on $(0,1]$.

Comment: Isn't it necessary to establish the integrability of the function logsinx to use this inequality?

Comment: @takecare Continuity of $\ln(\sin(x))$ on $(0,1]$ is sufficient for integrability.

Comment: I don't get it...The function is unbounded on $(0,1]$, so isn't it necessary to show that the limit $\lim_{c \to 0^+} \int_c^1 f$ is finite? From my knowledge on Improper Integrals, you've only shown that ln(sinx) is integrable on $[c,1]$ for every $c\in (0,1]$.